# PHP: How to know if link is a valid youtube link?

Tags: php

Here are examples.

```
www.youtube.com,
http://www.youtube.com/,
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoB8t0B4jx4
```

I don't care if it has video or just youtube url but just valid url.
What I want to do is when i know that it is a valid youtube url i will check if it has video ID.
If it has ID i will add iframe for video and if has no it will be just plane text.
I just want to know if a link is a valid youtube weather it has http or not, weather it has
ID or not.
Im not good at regular expression now and i need the code now pls help thanks in advance

Comment: `if(explode('.', $link)[1]=='youtube.com)//do stuff`

Comment: to other who (-) vote my question sorry i dont look on regex earlier because i did not know regex is short for regular expression T_T

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php
$url = "www.youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM";

$regex_pattern = "/(youtube.com|youtu.be)\/(watch)?(\?v=)?(\S+)?/";
$match;

if(preg_match($regex_pattern, $url, $match)){
    echo "Youtube video id is: ".$match[4];
}else{
    echo "Sorry, not a youtube URL";
}
```

## [Demo](http://ideone.com/4KltZr)

Look at the `stdout` section below in the demo

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then it should be simple as `youtube\.com/watch\?v=(.*)`

Comment: This doesn't account for shortened URL's like `https://youtu.be`